# How to return reviews of place with service areas but no location?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I've noticed for a while a problem to return reviews when using Google Places API.

Indeed, for businesses that have a location, it works without problems.

When I use the Place ID of a business that doesn't have a location but have service areas, it no longer works.

After several analyzes, I notice when I use console.log on "**google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus**", it returns "**NOT FOUND**" for businesses without location. Yet they do exist.

Here is my code on Codepen with two Place IDs. The first has a location and works, the other one has service areas and doesn't work.

```
 window.addEventListener("load", function() {

    //////////////////////////////////////////////  
    // ┌──────────────────────────────────────┐ //
    // │ Google Place                         │ //
    // │ Based on Google-Place.js             │ //
    // └──────────────────────────────────────┘ //
    //////////////////////////////////////////////

    var parameters = {

            selector : '#google-reviews',
            min_rating : 1,
            id : 'ChIJ4wzGc-h7wUcR3ncdI5-EELg' // (GMB ("FirewooD") with specified location) => Work, it return 5 last reviews
//    id : 'ChIJsWBxIXYhwkcRtbHQpK2MnNc' // (GMB ("MD Jardins") without location but with service areas) => Doesn't work

        }

    // ─────────────────────────────────────── //

    var initialize_place = function(c){

        var request = {

        placeId: parameters.id

        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-plug')),
              service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

        service.getDetails(request, function(place, status) {

        console.log("status: " + status);

        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
          c(place.reviews);         
        }

        });

    } // end initialize_place()

    var sort_by_date = function(ray) {

      ray.sort(function(a, b){

        var keyA = new Date(a.time),
            keyB = new Date(b.time);

        // Compare the 2 dates
        if(keyA < keyB) return 1;
        if(keyA > keyB) return -1;

        return 0;

      });
        return ray;

    } // end sort_by_date()

    var filter_minimum_rating = function(reviews){

      for (var i = reviews.length -1; i >= 0; i--) {

          if(reviews[i].rating < parameters.min_rating){
            reviews.splice(i,1);
          }

      }

      return reviews;

    } // end filter_minimum_rating()

    var renderRating = function(rating){

          var html = "",
                star = renderAverageStars(rating);

          html = "<div class='average-rating'><h4>"+star+"</h4></div>";

    } // end renderRating()

    var shorten_name = function(name) {
      if (name.split(" ").length > 1) {

         var xname = "";
         xname = name.split(" ");
         return xname[0] + " " + xname[1][0] + ".";

      }
    } // end shorten_name()

    var renderReviews = function(reviews){

      reviews = sort_by_date(reviews);
          reviews = filter_minimum_rating(reviews);

      console.log(reviews);
          var html = "",
            row_count = (5 > 0)? 5 - 1 : reviews.length - 1;

      for (var i = 0; reviews.length > i; i++) {

          var stars = renderStars(reviews[i].rating),
              date = convertTime(reviews[i].time),
              name = reviews[i].author_name,
              photo = reviews[i].profile_photo_url,
              text = reviews[i].text;

          html = "<div class='review-item CJS_slide'><div class='inner'><img class='photo' src='"+photo+"' alt=\""+name+"\"><div class='review-wrap'>"+stars+"<span class='review-author'>"+name+"</span><span class='review-date'>"+date+"</span><p class='review-text'>"+text+"</p></div></div></div>";

          document.querySelector(parameters.selector+' .CJS_wrapper').innerHTML += html;

      }

    }; // end renderReviews()

    var renderStars = function(rating){

      var stars = "<div class='review-stars'><ul>";

      // fill in gold stars
      for (var i = 0; i < rating; i++) {
        stars = stars+"<li><i class='star'></i></li>";
      };

      // fill in empty stars
      if(rating < 5){
        for (var i = 0; i < (5 - rating); i++) {
          stars = stars+"<li><i class='star inactive'></i></li>";
        };
      }
      stars = stars+"</ul></div>";
      return stars;

  } // end renderStars()

    var convertTime = function(UNIX_timestamp){

      var a = new Date(UNIX_timestamp * 1000),
          months = ['Janvier','Février','Mars','Avril','Mai','Juin','Juillet','Août','Septembre','Octobre','Novembre','Decembre'],
          time = a.getDate() + ' ' + months[a.getMonth()] + ' ' + a.getFullYear();

      return time;
    } // end convertTime()

    initialize_place(renderReviews);


});
```

https://codepen.io/bprodagnc/pen/zYGRERj

To retrieve the Place ID I use the DevTools on the "Write review" button ([Check the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCPG8.jpg)).

Is this a bug? How to return reviews from a business that has only service areas, to display them on the company's website?

Comment: Are you sure about that place id?

Comment: You *could* have shared the Business name too, just to avoid me (us) spend 5 minutes finding it based on a screenshot... Anyway! The place ID I get for this place is `ChIJjd1QNyA3wkcROXYaGkufQ0g` and not the one you provided. I am not getting any reviews either though.

Comment: * But I am not seeing any reviews on Google Maps website either...

Comment: Hey,


I'm sorry, I didn't think the Business names was useful for this problem. I've just updated my post and added names.

I have checked and rechecked the Place IDs and they are correct. They have both many reviews. Where did you find the ID place that you mentioned?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I found it by searching the Places API with the name and location that was on your screenshot (*md-jardin*).

Comment: The way you are getting the place ID from what appears to be the Google Maps website isn't documented. You are querying the Places API so you should also rely on the Places API for getting the appropriate Place IDs. I'd need to do some tests but even on your screenshot it looks strange... why is it "md-jardin" on the map and "MD Jardins" in the sidebar... ?

Comment: Via the Places API, the only 2 businesses I am able to find with a *similar* name are *md-jardin, Rue Fonds Pecriaux, Manage, Belgium* with place id `ChIJjd1QNyA3wkcROXYaGkufQ0g` and *M.D. Jardin, Tournai, Belgique* with place id `ChIJM1NaP_fhwkcRTD2jnF-eoBw`.

Comment: It might well be that all "service areas" businesses are not in the API because all places usually return a place geometry (which contains a location) and these might not have a location, or Google prevents them from being retrieved because of that. I don't know of any official documentation on that topic though.

Comment: Like I wrote in my JavaScript code and on my screenshot, the business name is "MD Jardins", not "md-jardin" or "M.D. Jardin". I just saw the "md-jardin" on the screen, it's another pointer proposed by Google Maps. The business that concerns me is represented by the red area on the map.

It seems that there is a real problem for "service areas" businesses. I tried to contact Google support but I didn't receive anything. I can't find any official information on this recent change and it's very annoying.

Thank you for spending time with me on my problem :).

Comment: Seems like this is another issue / feature request that Google is patiently not willing to implement: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35828187

Comment: It's very strange because 1 or 2 months ago, retrieving reviews for Service Areas Businesses worked well for me ...

I found another person who has the same problem as me, but apparently without resolution : https://wordpress.org/support/topic/html_attributions-status-not_found/

Comment: Are you sure about that? The only way to get reviews is to query for place details AFAIK. And this returns "No results". And I suppose it is so, because it *can't* return a location... I might be wrong though and it's actually the first time I am confronted to this issue.

Comment: Yes I am totally sure. The problem has only appeared since the beginning of 2020. Before that, it worked perfectly for several of my clients with their Google My Business with SAB.

This person has exactly the same problem since early 2020 : https://support.google.com/business/thread/29267660?hl=en&msgid=36341515

Comment: I'm afraid I've to wait until the end of the COVID-19 situation to expect something about Google.

Can you confirm that Place API is the only way to return reviews of a GMB on a website ?

Comment: Ok I am a bit surprised then, especially because of that issue I linked in my previous comment, which dates back from 2016. And yes, I believe a place details request with the place id is the only way to retrieve a place reviews.

Comment: I was also surprised by the date of the comments. I will continue to analyze the others declared issues, hoping to find a solution. Thank you for spending time with me on my problem :).